# Applying CSS to Bootstrap's Popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a popover and I want to apply CSS to it but my CSS is getting ignored. What could be the reason?

The JS creates following **markup** for popover:

```
<div class="popover fade bottom in" style="top: 24px; left: 461.281px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3>
        <div class="popover-content">Phone</div>
</div>
```

Default Style is:

```
element.style{
    top: 24px;
    left: 461.281px;
    display: block;
}
```

My **CSS**:

```
<style>
    .popover{
        left: 580px;
    }
</style>
```

Can I not overwrite the CSS?

Comment: you can overwrite it by adding !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `!important` because inline styles take the priority and you cannot override without `!important`.

```
.popover {
   left: 580px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using important is not considered a good practice, rather give it a id and style it.

```
<div id="popover" class="popover fade bottom in" style="top: 24px; left: 461.281px; 
display: block;">

<style>
#popover{
    left: 580px;
}
</style>
```